# Vaccine certificate conditions for Armenia entrance

Tags: covid-19, armenia

As I read in [Armenia Gov](https://www.gov.am/en/covid-travel-restrictions/), one can enter with a certification of complete of vaccine.

I want to know what vaccines are approved for that certificate? is Sinopharm certificate accepted?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.